# ¿Cómo puedo permitir que los usuarios muevan el slider del Centro de Control?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Estoy trabajando en una app que reproducirá archivos de sonido. El caso, es que si reproduzco algo desde la app de música de apple, me permite mover el slider y desplazarme entre la pista que esta reproduciéndose.

[image: Captura de muestra en slider movible]

En otras apps como Spotify o Overcast, no se puede.

[image: Captura de muestra]

Hasta ahora, he logrado que se actualice este slider con el tiempo que lleva reproducida la pista, así como el tiempo tiempo total, pero no veo como puedo hacer el slider editable y que el usuario lo pueda mover. ¿Alguna pista?.

Por cierto, para los botones estoy utilizando este código:

```
MPRemoteCommandCenter *commandCenter = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];

NSArray *commands = @[commandCenter.playCommand, commandCenter.pauseCommand, commandCenter.nextTrackCommand, commandCenter.previousTrackCommand, commandCenter.bookmarkCommand, commandCenter.changePlaybackPositionCommand, commandCenter.changePlaybackRateCommand, commandCenter.dislikeCommand, commandCenter.enableLanguageOptionCommand, commandCenter.likeCommand, commandCenter.ratingCommand, commandCenter.seekBackwardCommand, commandCenter.seekForwardCommand, commandCenter.skipBackwardCommand, commandCenter.skipForwardCommand, commandCenter.stopCommand, commandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand];

for (MPRemoteCommand *command in commands) {
    [command removeTarget:nil];
    [command setEnabled:NO];
}

[commandCenter.playCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(playTrack)];
[commandCenter.pauseCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(pauseTrack)];
[commandCenter.playCommand setEnabled:YES];
[commandCenter.pauseCommand setEnabled:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que ninguna app aparte de la de música es capaz de hacer eso. Debe ser por que utiliza algún framework privado, pero claro, si tu aplicación utiliza frameworks privados será rechazada por la App Store. No obstante, si aún así tienes interés en saber como hacerlo, puedes echar un vistazo a esta URL:

https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/PrivateFrameworks/MediaPlayerUI.framework/_MPUControlCenterDetailSlider.h

Es un enlace a uno de los frameworks privados que utiliza Apple internamente por si deseas toquetear un poco a modo de testing. En este hay métodos como `beginTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:` o `continueTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:` que tiene pinta de que podrían servirte.